Eclipse CDT Remote Application Error: File Upload to Raspberry Pi Fails with 'No Such File
Problem Summary:
I am using Eclipse CDT to build and deploy a C++ application to a remote Raspberry Pi target using the "Remote Application" run configuration. The build completes successfully on the host system, and the executable (A11_HelloWorld) is located in the directory Debug_with_Cross GCC. However, during the file upload to the Raspberry Pi (/tmp/remotetest/), I receive the error:
Error during file upload. Could not write file: /home/hfu/eclipse-sheet7/A11_HelloWorld/Debug_with_Cross GCC/A11_HelloWorld. No such file 
Additional Details:
The remote directory /tmp/remotetest/ exists on the Raspberry Pi and has 777 permissions.
I can manually execute the program on the host (./A11_HelloWorld) and manually upload it to the Raspberry Pi using scp.
The issue seems related to Eclipse failing to locate or upload the file during the remote execution process.
What I’ve tried:
Verified file paths in the Eclipse configuration (both local and remote paths).
Checked permissions on the host and the Raspberry Pi.
Manually tested file uploads, which work without issues.
Goal: Fix the file upload issue in Eclipse so that I can run the remote application successfully.
